# Why this is showing a syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax

I don't know if there is a syntax error. Just going over my head.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwl0P.jpg

Edit:- I had to post an image bbecause I cant connect my laptop to wifi due tl hardware problem. Another thing is that, internet connection here is very disturing. It took almost 2 minutes to post that image anyway.

Comment: What is that curly bracket on line 75?

Comment: Please add the code to the question and describe the context a bit.

Comment: thought to block the function. @stephen

Comment: don't have that much time. have to complete the full project within 48hours. @anton

Comment: If you're not willing to take a bit of time to properly post the code then don't be surprised if no one bothers to help.

Comment: [This page](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) nicely sums up the reasons why posting an image of your code is unacceptable. I can't imagine why a copy/paste would take longer than a screenshot would. As @MichaelSwartz said, put in a bit of effort for us and we'll put in a bit of effort for you.

Comment: @MohammadAzizulIslamAsif Without you putting in the slightest bit of effort to post the code (taking ~30 seconds of your time), we're not going to put in that tiny bit of our time to help you.

Comment: it doesn't take 30 seconds.

Comment: I cant connect my laptop to wifi. That's why I cant copy/paste it. i'd have done that if I could. I think I should have mentioned this in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, just at a glance.

As Rakesh's answer states, `platform00.upper() = input("etc")` is not valid syntax, and should replaced with `platform00 = input("etc").upper()`. The way you have it, you're attempting to set a value to a non-variable, specifically the return value of a function.

For a second thing, you have a curly brace in your code, on line 74 (`def learnpython() : {`) as if to define a function. Python is a whitespace-based language; functions are defined by indentation, not curly braces. You're thinking of a language like the C family, or Java. Python does use curly braces, but curly braces denote a dictionary. Since `foo = bar` is not valid syntax for initializing a dictionary, it's giving you a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks. Since you gave me the detailed answer where I didn't even bother to write it down, you appreciate a big thanks :-)

Comment: @MohammadAzizulIslamAsif - you still should've copy/pasted your code. The only reason I gave this answer is because the problem was a dead-simple syntax error visible through a few seconds of scanning. If your issue had required anything more intensive to fix, then no, you probably wouldn't have gotten any answer at all. Just keep it in mind.

Comment: Dead-simple for you only. It's pretty hard for me.

Comment: I cant connect my laptop to wifi. That's why I cant copy/paste it. i'd have done that if I could. I think I should have mentioned this in the question.